# PWA - Vue - WP Rest Api

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, woocommerce-rest-api

I have build a ecommerce website using wordpress and i have used python for scraping data for others websites  and compare the prices and bulk upload products with csv file.

My thought is to start learning Vue and  build it as PWA because in know days and in the future this will be essential. Also i consider to use WP Rest Api to buid it. Until now the most looks clear for me.

Μy concern is, that i would like to avoid using python and have my bot run 24 hours to download data which i need everday. **I would like take the prices for each product in real time for some external websites(for example specify the html which the price is and write it in a specific field in my website)**.

Can that be done is some way?
Please advice

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to rely on the API of the pages, a lot of websites provide such an API with the actual price that you could fetch.

Also if i could recommend you something take a look at the [Nuxt/PWA Module](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/), it works out of the box and has tons of configuration options and SSR support if you want that for your SEO optimization.

Comment: If there isn't any API , is any way to get real time html data from the external pages?  I will check  Nuxt/PWA Module, but now my thought is to use vuestorefront.

Comment: @mpantogi ah yes storefront looks better for your purpose, im not sure i think its possible somehow but usually there should be an API if not then you can try googling how to fetch html from other websites

Comment: <<Fetch>> as i see may be the word to get better google results fo that i need. Thank you